# Javascript AppendChild autorefreshes the form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small code which moves the list items from one  list to another list.  The code is working in IE8, but not IE10 or chrome.  After onclick event, list items moves from Left to right list, but then, page seems page gets automatically refreshed.

If I remove the  tag then code works, But I need the  tag.  How do I stop the javascript to not to refresh the page when onclick event happens.  I tried  few solutions mentioned in other posts, but none worked.  Appreciate if you could help me on this. 
  I didn't want to post all code. Hence I have create a sample page  for that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 http-equiv="content-type">
  <title>Test</title>
  <script>
function AppendList()
{
//event.preventDefault(); I also tried AppendList(event)
var node = document.getElementById("batchReportLists0").lastChild;
document.getElementById("batchReportLists1").appendChild(node);
alert("Added Last Item");
//return false;
//window.onbeforeunload = function(){
//return "Refresh";
}
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="batchReportForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="1"
 cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
        <select multiple="multiple" size="15" name="T1"
 class="bodyText" id="batchReportLists0">
        <option>Msg1</option>
        <option>Msg2</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td> <button onclick="AppendList();">
&gt;&gt;&gt; </button>
        </td>
        <td>
        <select multiple="multiple" size="15" name="T2"
 class="bodyText" id="batchReportLists1">
        <option>Msg3</option>
        <option>Msg4</option>
        </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What tag are you adding/removing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a

```
<button type="button">Button</button>
```

By default, `<button>` acts as a submit.